# run a macro from a closed workbook and save

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a macro i would like to run at a set day and time without having to open it and run.

i found [this link](http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/run-macro-without-opening-excel-using-vbscript/), which says its possible via VBscript

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Sales.xlsm'!SalesModule.SalesTotal"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

and to get it to save just added

```
objExcel.Application.Save
```

before application.quit

yet i cant seem to get it to work, could someone please tell me what im doing wrong

```
'Code should be placed in a .vbs file
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.xlsm'!Module1.weeklyF"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Save
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save an application. You need to save the workbook. Assign the workbook to a variable and then save ie `Dim wbSalesTotal as Workbook`, `wbSalesTotal.Save`.

Answer (score 0):

Start Excel, Alt + F11, F2. This is Excel's object model. If it isn't here you can't do it.

```
objExcel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

is one way